# How do I make an application/xml POST with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, post

I need to make a little handler that takes some querystring data and formulates a post to the BaseCamp API with it. Problem is I am not exactly sure how this is done, how to I specify which URL it is going to, and where to I put the XML that I build (I have the XML built already). And then how to I 'press GO' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this [example](http://authors.aspalliance.com/stevesmith/articles/netscrape2.asp), it shows you how to post from ASP.NET, very straightforward.

Comment: yeah I was looking at that earlier, how do I attach the XML?